# $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() always returns false in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to check to see when an action has been requested by AJAX or not and the condition is always returning false in Zend Framework.

Here is my conditional:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) { 
    // AJAX
} else {
   // not AJAX
}
```

I'm sure this is the right condition, because it works elsewhere in my code.  I guess I'm wondering how I check what URL the request is coming from? If I die on `$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` and `print_r()` the result, I get 1.  I guess that means it's working.  But something is amiss and I can't figure out what.  I've commented out all of the other code in the action and I still get the same error -- it thinks it's not AJAX.

How do I begin to figure out what's wrong?  The request is coming from an AJAX file upload script.  So I would think that would automatically be an AJAX request, but apparently not.  Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Does the upload script use an `iframe` - maybe that can be the problem.

Comment: It does use an iframe, yes.  Do I need the URL of that iframe, or something like that?

Comment: Setting the url of an iframe(or uploading a file through it) is not a [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), though it "feels" like one.

Comment: Maybe sharing more info about this upload script can be of help.

Comment: OK, so there's no way to detect if its an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Here is the script http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Comment: The condition in the question is fine, the request itself is not AJAX.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think I know another way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it thinks it's not AJAX

Judging by the comments of the question - you're right.